Are there any other sequences of functions besides $\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j) $ for which both their sum and the sum of their reciprocals telescope?
If
$p_k(x)
=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)
$,
then both
$\sum_{j=a}^b p_k(x+j)
$
and
$\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_k(x+j)}
$
can be written as
telescoping sums
so we get
$$\sum_{j=a}^b p_k(x+j)
=\dfrac1{k+1}\left(p_{k+1}(x+b+1)-p_{k+1}(x+a)\right)
$$
and
$$\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k}(x+j)}
=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+a)}- \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+b+1)}\right).
$$
My question:
Are there any other
sequences of functions
besides
$p_k(x)
$
for which both
$\sum_{j=a}^b p_k(x+j)
$
and
$\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k}(x+j)}
$
telescope?
Here are the derivations of
these results.
(As is often the case, nothing in these derivations
is original.)
$p_k(x)
=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)
$
$\begin{array}\\
p_k(x+1)-p_k(x)
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+1+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k}(x+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(x+j)(x+k-x)\\
&=k\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(x+j)\\
&=k\prod_{j=0}^{k-2}(x+j+1)\\
&=kp_{k-1}(x)\\
\end{array}
$
so
$p_{k-1}(x)
=\dfrac1{k}(p_k(x+1)-p_k(x))
$
or
$p_{k}(x)
=\dfrac1{k+1}(p_{k+1}(x+1)-p_{k+1}(x))
$.
Therefore
$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=a}^b p_k(x+j)
&=\sum_{j=a}^b\dfrac1{k+1}(p_{k+1}(x+j+1)-p_{k+1}(x+j))\\
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\sum_{j=a}^b(p_{k+1}(x+j+1)-p_{k+1}(x+j))\\
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\left(\sum_{j=a}^bp_{k+1}(x+j+1)-\sum_{j=a}^bp_{k+1}(x+j)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\left(\sum_{j=a+1}^{b+1}p_{k+1}(x+j)-\sum_{j=a}^bp_{k+1}(x+j)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\left(p_{k+1}(x+b+1)-p_{k+1}(x+a)\right)\\
\end{array}
$
Similarly,
$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p_k(x)}-\dfrac1{p_k(x+1)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(x+j)}\\
&=\dfrac{x+k}{\prod_{j=0}^{k}(x+j)}-\dfrac{x}{\prod_{j=0}^{k}(x+j)}\\
&=\dfrac{x+k-x}{\prod_{j=0}^{k}(x+j)}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{\prod_{j=0}^{k}(x+j)}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{p_{k+1}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$
so
$\dfrac1{p_{k+1}(x)}
=\dfrac1{k}\left(\dfrac1{p_k(x)}-\dfrac1{p_k(x+1)}\right)
$
or
$\dfrac1{p_{k}(x)}
=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x)}-\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+1)}\right)
$.
Therefore
$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k}(x+j)}
&=\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j)}-\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j+1)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j)}-\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j+1)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\sum_{j=a}^b \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j)}-\sum_{j=a+1}^{b+1} \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+j)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+a)}- \dfrac1{p_{k-1}(x+b+1)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Fascinating problem

Did you make any progress on your side ? Cheers :-)

Nope. I may come back to it after I can, maybe, see what going from n to n+1 can give me.
